# Nested PDO queries

Tags: php, pdo

I've run into some trouble trying to execute MSSQL queries using PDO.
I have a table called Computer with 92 computers listed. They all have a respective ID 1-92.

I am using the query: SELECT * FROM Computer to query the table. I want to add associated information to this query so I am outputting it inside a while-loop (this is eventually for table generation).

```
$queryDiskOperationLog = "SELECT * FROM Computer";

$queryHDDSResult = $connClient -> prepare($queryDiskOperationLog);
$queryHDDSResult->execute();

$queryDiskOperationLogResult = $connClient -> prepare($queryDiskOperationLog);
while ($rowHDDS = $queryHDDSResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $rowHDDS['Id'];
}
```

This output works great. I get 1-92 outputted. Trouble begins when I start adding other queries.
Whenever I add another query inside the while-loop the output of the first query is altered and it only outputs uneven numbers (ie. 1,3,5,7...)

I am using the same PDO::FETCH_ASSOC method to get results from the other query and variable names are distinctly different. Do you know what could cause this?

My final code looks like: (note I don't even echo the second query yet.

```
$queryDiskOperationLog = "SELECT * FROM Computer";
$queryHardDisk = "SELECT * FROM HardDisk";

$queryHDDSResult = $connClient -> prepare($queryDiskOperationLog);
$queryHDDSResult->execute();

$queryHardDiskResult = $connClient -> prepare($queryHardDisk);
$queryHardDiskResult ->execute();

$queryDiskOperationLogResult = $connClient -> prepare($queryDiskOperationLog);
while ($rowHDDS = $queryHDDSResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $rowHardDisk = $queryHardDiskResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $rowHDDS['Id'];
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code when you add another query and any errors you get

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just added my final code. The no errors, just that it starts skipping rows.

Comment: How do the other queries relate to this?

Comment: @user3783243 I don't see any relation between them, which is why I'm so confused. With the code I have they shouldn't affect each other what so ever. And they don't when I use a MySQL equivalent.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Possibly this is not the real code that you have shown us.

Comment: @Dharman This is the result using real code:
Single query:
1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192
Double query:
135791113151719212325272931333537394143454749515355575961636567697173757779818385878991

Comment: Nested queries are almost always the wrong way to do things. You should use a JOIN and retrieve the data from both tables with a single query.

Comment: That sounds like you have `$queryHDDSResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` in the `while`